# Can you charge then grapple?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, grapple, charge

Can you [charge](http://dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#charge) an enemy then [grapple](http://dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#grapple) that enemy at the end of the charge instead of making a normal melee attack?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Yes, you may grapple as part of a charge

This can be seen on the combat chapter ([SRD reference](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm),
*Table: Miscellaneous Actions*):

> **Grapple²**
>
> 2: These attack forms substitute for a melee attack, not an action. As melee attacks, they can be used once in an attack or **charge action**, one or more times in a full attack action, or even as an attack of opportunity

Answer (score 5):

## Yes you can charge and then grapple instead of attacking

The use of charge allows you to make a *single melee attack* (which can be replaced by your grapple) after your moving with a +2 bonus to attack, which also applies to your grapple check.

> Attacking on a Charge
>
> After moving, you may make a single melee attack. You get a +2 bonus on the attack roll and take a –2 penalty to your AC until the start of your next turn.

The grappling description you have linked goes as follows:

> Starting a Grapple
>
> To start a grapple, you need to grab and hold your target. Starting a grapple requires a successful melee attack roll. If you get multiple attacks , you can attempt to start a grapple multiple times (at successively lower base attack bonuses).

The condition of requiring a melee attack is met for the grapple through the charge as well.

However be careful, as you are provoking an attack of opportunity on the target you are attempting to grapple and have -2 penalty to AC until the start of your next turn through the charge.

> Attack of Opportunity.
>
> You provoke an attack of opportunity from the target you are trying to grapple. If the attack of opportunity deals damage, the grapple attempt fails. (Certain monsters do not provoke attacks of opportunity when they attempt to grapple, nor do characters with the Improved Grapple feat.) If the attack of opportunity misses or fails to deal damage, proceed to Step 2.

Following the grapple rules, you are compelled to do repeated opposed grapple checks during the grapple, depending on the action.

*Grapple check* is like a melee attack roll. The check is: Base attack bonus + Strength modifier + special size modifier. (note: after the charge turn, the +2 bonus to attack rolls will no longer apply to the checks as your charge is over and you are in grapple status)

Special size modifier is as follows: Colossal +16, Gargantuan +12, Huge +8, Large +4, Medium +0, Small -4, Tiny -8, Diminutive -12.

Comment: I think bonus on attack rolls aplies only to touch attack charger makes to initiate a grapple. Grapple check  is like attack roll, but it doesn't recieve all the bonuses. If you grapple with +1 weapon for example it will increase your initial touch attack bonus but will it apply to grapple checks?

Comment: No it will not. I have added those bits of information to my answer.

Comment: *(note: the initial charge bonus will no longer apply to the checks as your charge is over and you are in grapple status)* Charge is a full round action.  "it's over" is at the end of your full round action. Also, see Pounce where not only all initial attacks gain the bonus, but so do Rake attacks.

Comment: The note is meant to be after that round, the grapple lasting for more than a round will no longer benefit from the initial charge attack's bonus. I was trying to explain the grapple checks after that turn and why they no longer benefit from the charge with the grapple check parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. A grapple can be used instead of any melee attack:

> Starting a grapple requires a successful melee attack roll. If you get multiple attacks, you can attempt to start a grapple multiple times (at successively lower base attack bonuses).

Since the attack at the end of a charge is one of those, you can grapple instead of the usual effects of attacking. The +2 bonus to attacks you get for charging also applies.

I’m not aware of anything that says this explicitly, however. The only thing I can point to is the grapple rules saying they replace an attack, that grapple checks are “like” attacks (and carry on any iterative penalties, anyway), and nothing about charging says you can’t grapple. It certainly also seems to make narrative sense, to me anyway, so I don’t see why they would restrict it, which encourages me in believing that they *didn’t* intentionally.

Comment: Could you please quote the source of the "a grapple can be used instead of any melee attack" assumption?

Comment: [SRD reference](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm), side table: *These attack forms substitute for a melee attack, not an action. As melee attacks, they can be used once in an attack or charge action, one or more times in a full attack action, or even as an attack of opportunity.*

Comment: @ShadowKras That really ought to be an answer; I missed that entirely.